# Returning functions from functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm learning how to return functions from other functions in JavaScript.  Here is my code that works:

```js
var passengers = [
    { name: "Jane", ticket: "coach" },
    { name: "Evel", ticket: "firstclass" },
    { name: "John", ticket: "coach" },
    { name: "Bob", ticket: "premium"}
];

function createDrinkOrder(passenger) {
    var orderFunction;
    if (passenger.ticket === 'firstclass') {
        orderFunction = function() {
            console.log(passenger.name + ', would you like wine or cocktail?');
        };
    } else if (passenger.ticket === 'premium') {
        orderFunction = function() {
            console.log(passenger.name + ', would you like some wine?');
        };
    } else {
        orderFunction = function() {
            console.log(passenger.name + ', soda or water?');
        };
    }
    return orderFunction;
}

function serveOnePassenger(passenger) {
    var getDrinkOrderFunction = createDrinkOrder(passenger);
    getDrinkOrderFunction();
    // createDrinkOrder(passenger);
}

// General function to serve passengers:
function servePassengers(passengers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
        serveOnePassenger(passengers[i]);
    }
}

servePassengers(passengers);
```

My question is about 'serverOnePassenger' function: when I comment out the first 2 lines in this function and uncomment the 3rd line instead, nothing happens in the console anymore. Why do I have to declare a variable and then assign a function to it, and only then call this var in order for this code to work? Thanks!

Comment: Your third line is returning a function, you're just not executing it. Try `createDrinkOrder(passenger)()`.

Comment: The function you're trying to call doesn't exist till you execute the function that creates it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own question title is basically the answer: you've written the `createDrinkOrder()` function as something that **returns** another function. If you make a function but never call it, the function won't do anything.

You don't need a variable involved as in your `serveOnePassenger()` function. You could create the function and call it with one statement:

```
  createDrinkOrder(passenger)();
```

That calls `createDrinkOrder()` and then immediately uses the returned value as a function.

Comment: Thank you, it make total sense now!  I saw this syntax before but I didn't know what it meant.

Answer (score 5):

You must call both `createDrinkOrder` and the function that it created, try this

```
(createDrinkOrder(passenger))();
```

Let's go through this step by step

- `createDrinkOrder(passenger)` calls `createDrinkOrder` which returns an anonymous function
- `(...)()` calls that anonymous function

Comment: Thank you, akuhn!  I understand now what this syntax mean.  It works both ways now.

Comment: @mariablair glad to hear! If my answer was helpful, consider accepting it with the checkmark.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely - because you only get back the function - you never actually call it... Try this instead:

```
createDrinkOrder(passenger)();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You don't. Your problem is that the function you call returns another function, but the function that actually logs the text isn't called. If you call the returned function like this: `createDrinkOrder(passenger)()`, it will call both functions.

```js
var passengers = [
    { name: "Jane", ticket: "coach" },
    { name: "Evel", ticket: "firstclass" },
    { name: "John", ticket: "coach" },
    { name: "Bob", ticket: "premium"}
];

function createDrinkOrder(passenger) {
    var orderFunction;
    if (passenger.ticket === 'firstclass') {
        orderFunction = function() {
            console.log(passenger.name + ', would you like wine or cocktail?');
        };
    } else if (passenger.ticket === 'premium') {
        orderFunction = function() {
            console.log(passenger.name + ', would you like some wine?');
        };
    } else {
        orderFunction = function() {
            console.log(passenger.name + ', soda or water?');
        };
    }
    return orderFunction;
}

function serveOnePassenger(passenger) {
    // var getDrinkOrderFunction = createDrinkOrder(passenger); // Because this returns an anonymous function
    // getDrinkOrderFunction(); // It must be executed to have the expected result
    createDrinkOrder(passenger)(); // This line both returns the function, and executes it.
}

// General function to serve passengers:
function servePassengers(passengers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
        serveOnePassenger(passengers[i]);
    }
}

servePassengers(passengers);
```

Answer (score 1):

`createDrinkOrder`is returning a function object.  The third line of code calls `createDrinkOrder` which returns a function, but never calls the returned function.  You don't necessarily need assign the value returned by `createDrinkOrder` to a variable, but you do need to make sure that the function it returns gets called.  You could do it like this without using a variable: `createDrinkOrder(passenger)();`